# How can I delete specific rows in parse.com?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, row

I have objects in Parse called "Post" and within that, I have columns called "title" and "content". I am trying to ask the user for an input value and save this as "remove". If the user's input value ("remove") matches a "title" value already saved in parse.com, I want to delete the entire row in parse, so that both the "title", "content" and everything else in the row is deleted. The deleting part is not working so I am wondering if my code is actually making it go through all the data saved in parse and find the one that matches the user's input and then delete it. 
What am I doing incorrectly and what can I change to make it delete the entire row?
Thank you in advance.

```
function getPosts(){
        var query = new Parse.Query(Post);
        query.find({
          success: function(results){
            for(var i in results){
                var title = results[i].get("title");
                var content = results[i].get("content");

                var remove = $("#post-remove").val();
                console.log("Remove: "+remove);
                console.log("MAC Address: " +title);
                console.log("place: "+content);

                if (title == remove)
                {
                    window.alert("The MAC address matches.");
                    console.log(remove+" matches " + title+ " and is located in " +content);
                    var Post = Parse.Object.extend("Post");
                    var query = new Parse.Query(Post);
                    query.find("objectId", {
                      success: function(yourObj){
                        //console.log(yourObj);
                        //Post.destroy({});        //if title matches remove, delete the Post (title and content) (but it's not deleting it)

                        Post.remove("title");
                        Post.remove("content");

                      }
                    });
              }
            }
          }
        });
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify and add a bit to @JakeT's acceptable answer:

1) find objects to delete like this:

```
function postsMatching(title) {
    var Post = Parse.Object.extend("Post");
    var query = new Parse.Query(Post);
    query.equalTo("title", title);
    return query.find();
}
```

2) Delete an array of parse objects like this:

```
Parse.Object.destroyAll(posts);
```

3) Put the two ideas together (returning a promise to find then delete) like this:

```
var title = $("#post-remove").val();
postsMatching(title).then(function(posts) {
    console.log("deleting " + JSON.stringify(posts));
    Parse.Object.destroyAll(posts);
}, function(error) {
    console.log("error " + JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

Comment: I am getting an error that says "Illegal return statement" for the "return postsMatching(title).then(function(posts) {"    part, but if I take the return out, it still doesn't perform the delete. How can I fix this?

Comment: you'd get that syntax error if the code was not contained inside a function.  Is it in a function?  If not, remove both returns (they are only for the caller to know when the execution is complete.  also, I added some code to help you debug.

Comment: If I want to use the same process but instead of deleting the entire row, replace the object with a new value, can I just change the "Pase.Object.destroyAll(posts);"   to  "objects.set("newlocation", newlocation);" where newlocation is a variable that stores the user's input of the new object?

Comment: It might make sense as another question so we can see the surrounding code, but yes, you can put whatever JS code in the resolution function (in the `then` function) that you need.  Remember if you change a parse object, you'll need to call save() on it to make the changes persist in the data.

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately it's not working. I've created a new question asking about this, would you mind taking a look? Thank you!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33863760/how-can-i-replace-specific-objects-in-parse-to-objects-inputted-by-the-user/33864104#33864104

Answer (score 0):

First of, you can use the `Parse.Query.equalTo(key, value)` method to filter for the Post/s you are looking for. That will render a lot of your logic unnecessary.

Additionally, since most parse calls are asynchronous, I would suggest learning about Parse Promises and using those instead of the call backs you're using.

Finally, you don't need a second nested query, since you already have the object you are trying to destroy. You just need to call `destroy()` on that object, and if you have some extra content you need to take care of deleting (i.e., your 'content' is a pointer to another object that is owned *only* by the Post you are deleting), you should set up a `beforeDestroy()` trigger for the Post object in your cloud code that will delete that pointer as well.

Comment: Thank you for your help!