# How can I replace specific objects in parse to objects inputted by the user?

Tags: javascript, object, parse-platform, replace

I have objects in Parse called "Post" and within that, I have columns called "title" and "content". I am trying to ask the user for an input value and save this as a variable, also called "content". If the user's input value ("content") matches a "content" value already saved in parse.com, I want to replace the "content" value in parse.com with the variable saved in "newlocation" (also inputted by the user).

The replacing part is not working and I am getting the error "objects.set is not a function". What am I doing incorrectly and what can I change so that if the variable "content" matches a content value in parse.com, it is replaced with the variable saved in "newlocation"? Thank you in advance.

My code is shown below:

```
      function postsSameAs(content){
          var Post = Parse.Object.extend("Post");
          var query = new Parse.Query(Post);
          query.equalTo("content", content);
          return query.find();

      } 

      $("#post-form-change").submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        var content = $("#post-original").val();
        var newlocation = $("#post-new").val();

        postsSameAs(content).then(function(objects){
            console.log("replacing " + JSON.stringify(objects));
            objects.set("newlocation", newlocation);  //should replace the "content" value in parse.com to the variable saved in "newlocation"

            return objects.save();
            window.alert("You have successfully replaced " + content + " to " + newlocation);
        }, function(error) {
            console.log("error " + JSON.stringify(error));
        });         

      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the code is that find() resolves as an array of matching objects. `objects.set(...` is no good because objects is an array.   Do you expect only one Post from the query?  In that case, replace `query.find()` with `query.first()`

Comment: I am only trying to change the content value which is a column within parse.com if it matches the user's input, so I only want one object from the row. Doesn't query.first() get the very first object the user has saved though?

Comment: No, it returns the first object that satisfies the query.

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately, it's still not replacing the object to the new one.

Comment: I notice the text of your question says that you want to replace the object's "content" attribute, but the code says `set("newLocation", ...`. Shouldn't it say `set("content", ...`?  This being right depends on your data model.

Comment: Yes, you are right. That was a mistake on my part. It works now. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try `objects["newlocation"] = newLocation;`

Comment: When I tried that, it gave me the error "objects.save(); is not a function".

Comment: Why would you need `objects.save();`? `objects["newlocation"] = newLocation;` should automatically update the `objects` object. Simply `return objects`

Comment: Without the objects.save() part, it does not update the object in parse.com.

Comment: is objects.save a function you created? If so make sure it is reachable (i.e in   the same file, not in a limited scope and if in an external file then make sure its included in the main html file)